# Clock for submits faulty

Tags: bug, time

I found that the clock in the submits is faulty, like jumping from 1 min to 59 min, and going back on refreshing the page.

Here they changed the calendar postponing the switch from summertime to wintertime.

Could it be that?

Comment: Yes, most likely a difference between the time reported by your browser (via JavaScript) and actual time.